# Fingerprint authentication is not working in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screen_lock/lock_screen.dart';
import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';
import 'package:secret_keeper/screens/home_screen/Home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Authentication extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticationState createState() => _AuthenticationState();
}

class _AuthenticationState extends State<Authentication> {

  String _password, _key = "Password";
  bool _isFingerprintEnabled;
  String _fingerprintKey = "isFingerprintEnabled";

  LocalAuthentication auth = LocalAuthentication();
  bool _canCheckBiometric;
  List<BiometricType> _availableBiometric;
  String authorized = "Not authorized";

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    checkPassword();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _checkBiometric() async{
    bool canCheckBiometric;
    try{
      canCheckBiometric = await auth.canCheckBiometrics;
    } on PlatformException catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
    if(!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _canCheckBiometric = canCheckBiometric;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getAvailableBiometrics() async{
    List<BiometricType> availableBiometric;
    try{
      availableBiometric = await auth.getAvailableBiometrics();
    } on PlatformException catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
    if(!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _availableBiometric = availableBiometric;
    });
  }

  checkPassword() async{
    SharedPreferences _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _password = _preferences.getString(_key);
    _isFingerprintEnabled = _preferences.getBool(_fingerprintKey);
    showLockScreen(
      context: context,
      title: "Enter vault password",
      digits: 5,
      correctString: _password,
      cancelText: "Close",
      showBiometricFirst: true,
      canCancel: false,
      onUnlocked: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Home())),
      canBiometric: _isFingerprintEnabled,
      biometricAuthenticate: (context) async {
        bool authenticated = false;
        try{
          authenticated = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
              localizedReason: "Scan your finger print to authenticate",
              useErrorDialogs: true,
              stickyAuth: false
          );
        } on PlatformException catch(e){
          print(e);
        }
        // if(!mounted) return;

        if (authenticated) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code where I am using flutter_screen_lock library to show the lock screen everything is working properly here but when i add code for fingerprint authentication it started getting exception so I google for it then I found solution of it where they said after changing FlutterActivity with FlutterFragmentActivity it'll solve my issue..

Here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.pawarsproduction.secret_keeper

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
}
```

after changing this my problem not solved but started getting many exceptions:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Waiting for Android SDK built for x86 to report its views...
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(int, boolean) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps() (BackStackRecord.java:439)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, int, int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, int, int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
I/art     ( 7504):   at boolean androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions() (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated() (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated() (FragmentController.java:246)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart() (FragmentActivity.java:542)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(android.app.Activity) (Instrumentation.java:1248)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.Activity.performStart() (Activity.java:6679)
I/art     ( 7504):   at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2609)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
I/art     ( 7504):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
I/art     ( 7504): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.WindowInsetsAnimation$Callback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pawarsproduction.secret_keeper-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.pawarsproduction.secret_keeper-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.pawarsproduction.secret_keeper-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
I/art     ( 7504):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
I/art     ( 7504):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
I/art     ( 7504):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.attachToFlutterEngine(io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine) (FlutterView.java:903)
I/art     ( 7504):   at android.view.View io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:294)
I/art     ( 7504):   at android.view.View io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (FlutterFragment.java:589)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (Fragment.java:2600)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(int, boolean) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps() (BackStackRecord.java:439)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, int, int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, int, int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
I/art     ( 7504):   at boolean androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions() (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated() (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated() (FragmentController.java:246)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart() (FragmentActivity.java:542)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(android.app.Activity) (Instrumentation.java:1248)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.Activity.performStart() (Activity.java:6679)
I/art     ( 7504):   at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2609)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
I/art     ( 7504):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
I/art     ( 7504): 
I/art     ( 7504): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.flutter.plugin.editing.ImeSyncDeferringInsetsCallback>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/WindowInsetsAnimation$Callback;
I/art     ( 7504):   at void io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.attachToFlutterEngine(io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine) (FlutterView.java:903)
I/art     ( 7504):   at android.view.View io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:294)
I/art     ( 7504):   at android.view.View io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (FlutterFragment.java:589)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (Fragment.java:2600)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(int, boolean) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps() (BackStackRecord.java:439)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, int, int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, int, int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
I/art     ( 7504):   at boolean androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions() (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated() (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated() (FragmentController.java:246)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart() (FragmentActivity.java:542)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(android.app.Activity) (Instrumentation.java:1248)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.Activity.performStart() (Activity.java:6679)
I/art     ( 7504):   at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2609)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
I/art     ( 7504):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
I/art     ( 7504): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.WindowInsetsAnimation$Callback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pawarsproduction.secret_keeper-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.pawarsproduction.secret_keeper-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.pawarsproduction.secret_keeper-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
I/art     ( 7504):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
I/art     ( 7504):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
I/art     ( 7504):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.attachToFlutterEngine(io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine) (FlutterView.java:903)
I/art     ( 7504):   at android.view.View io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:294)
I/art     ( 7504):   at android.view.View io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (FlutterFragment.java:589)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (Fragment.java:2600)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(int, boolean) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps() (BackStackRecord.java:439)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, int, int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, int, int) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
I/art     ( 7504):   at void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList) (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
I/art     ( 7504):   at boolean androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions() (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55643/YfmPHjAws2g=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/OpenGLRenderer( 7504): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer( 7504): Swap behavior 1
D/        ( 7504): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9354cf00, tid 7568
W/OpenGLRenderer( 7504): Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer( 7504): Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation( 7504): eglCreateContext: 0xb3205660: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 7504): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb3205660: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x96135860)
D/        ( 7504): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf5f2e40, tid 7551
D/EGL_emulation( 7504): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5abedc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x93550500)
I/Choreographer( 7504): Skipped 319 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation( 7504): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb3205660: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x96135860)
I/art     ( 7504): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 39997(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 19(956KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 636us total 566.730ms
W/System  ( 7504): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7504): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11743470
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7504): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11743470
W/FA      ( 7504): Callable skipped the worker queue.
D/EGL_emulation( 7504): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5abedc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x93550500)
W/ResourceType( 7504): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0x000002d0
W/art     ( 7504): Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504): java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:686)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:649)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:542)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:95)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:232)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:279)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:389)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:293)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:486)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2632)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:915)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:183)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.authenticateInternal(BiometricPrompt.java:749)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.authenticate(BiometricPrompt.java:658)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at io.flutter.plugins.localauth.AuthenticationHelper.authenticate(AuthenticationHelper.java:103)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at io.flutter.plugins.localauth.LocalAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(LocalAuthPlugin.java:120)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/local_auth( 7504):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
I/flutter ( 7504): PlatformException(error, You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity., null, java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
I/flutter ( 7504):  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:686)
I/flutter ( 7504):  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:649)
I/flutter ( 7504):  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:542)
I/flutter ( 7504):  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:95)
I/flutter ( 7504):  at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:232)
I/flutter ( 7504):  at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:279)
I/flutter ( 7504):  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:389)
I/flutter ( 7504):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:293)
I/flutter ( 7504):  at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:486)
I/flutter ( 7504):  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2632)
I/flutter ( 7504):  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentMan
I/flutter ( 7504): PlatformException(auth_in_progress, Authentication in progress, null, null)
```

Please help me to solve this problem :-(

Comment: Similar issue here. I tried to run the given example then the application got stopped without giving any error.

Comment: @VipinMalik Have you updated any plugins in your android folder?

Comment: I have updated the code as said by the documentation but the example was still not running, so I switched to another plugin named flutter_local_auth_invisible. I think this is not updated to the latest version so It worked fine but this library has some issue too like it doesn't send response when the user is not correct. So test that library before using it.

Comment: Have you changed Theme in your styles.xml?

Comment: No, I hadn't changed anything except mentioned in the documentation on the native side.

Comment: If you followed all documentation and get error then try to change <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> in styles.xml